# What is the best server side solution to distribute hundreds of images to millions of users of my app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, cdn

I have a free photo app that has millions of users, It has stickers and frames that I want to distribute from server to slim down apk and give more options to users. I am pretty experienced on android side while I have no idea what would be the best solution on server side. Should i buy a hosting solution and put all images there or use amazon service, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an ideal choice for storing vast amounts of data

> Amazon S3 is easy to use, with a simple web service interface to store
>   and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere on the web.

Have a look here 
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/

You will still need to interact with S3 via an SDK and programming language of your choice, java, .net, python, php.

You could then run one of those applications within AWS on EC2.
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Hope this answers your question.